# Creating a node modules for angular

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

I am trying to create a node module package for the first time.

i wrote a service that uses HttpClient module from "@angular/common/http"

my service code looks like this :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClientProvider {
    baseUrl: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    }

    // Preform the request and return a promise to the caller;
    private doRequest(requestType:string,url: string, body:any, options:any): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            return this.http[requestType](url,body,options).subscribe(data => {
                resolve(data);
            }, error => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    }

    // Use this function for GET WS
    getRequest(url: string): Promise<any> {
        return this.doRequest('get', url,{},{});
    }

    // Use this function for POST WS
    postRequest(url: string, body: any): Promise<any> {
        return this.doRequest('post', url, body,{});
    }
}
```

then i install it using "npm install" to my angular project.
after the installation is complete i add it to the providers in my app.module file.

the problem is when is try to use it inside a component i get the message"Error: No provider for HttpClient!"

i have tried to add HttpClient to providers list as well but it didn't change anything...

my component constructor looks like this

```
constructor(fb:FormBuilder, http: HttpClientProvider) {
    this.signInDetails = new SigninDetails();
    this.form = fb.group({
      'userName': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      'password': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])]
    });

    this.userName = this.form.controls['userName'];
    this.password = this.form.controls['password'];
  }
```

i do no understand what am i doing wrong... any suggestions ?

my AppModule looks like this

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [App],
  declarations: [
    App
  ],
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    PagesModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [ 
    HttpClientProvider,
    APP_PROVIDERS
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` is a service just like yours, so it has to be "provided" by some module. You should import `HttpClientModule` somewhere in your application. Preferably in `app.module` or `core.module` (if you have a core module). You can't just provide `HttpClient` in your modules because it needs other services as well. Lucky for you, `HttpClientModule` does that for you.

`app.module.ts`

```
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  exports: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I've edited my question.. i added the code for my AppModules but still no luck :(

Comment: Delete `HttpModule` from import array. It’s deprecated and may create conflicts with `HttpClientModule`

Comment: Try that, didn't work.. do you think that creating a module for my service can make difference ?

Comment: Take a look at this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1w9ae7?file=app/app.module.ts It works just fine. There must be something else wrong with your project